# How to cut of the DC supply from a high power motor control?

Tags: mosfet, switches, switch-mode-power-supply, high-current, igbt

For my project I built a BLDC motor controller.

Now I have to cut of the controller from the battery.
A relay is not    easy because common  my application needs >200Amps

The highside switches I found is the Voltage rating too low.
The max Voltage I found was 60V.

Battery voltage is 60V and the max current about 200A.

Also I am afraid of using semiconductors because they like to shoot trough after burning...

Comment: So.. you don't want to use a relay and you don't want to use semi-conductors.. um.... yank  the plug out the wall comes to mind..............

Comment: Sounds like a job for a contactor.. which is basically a relay. Something like these .http://www.hubbell-icd.com/general/100D-DC%20Devices.pdf

Comment: Consider how much stored rotational and electric energy is stored that needs to be dissipated.   Then consider speed brakes, mechanical or electrical  with gradual braking. e.g. PWM controlled short circuit current to gnd.

Comment: You do not say what operating voltage is. Explain your overall circuit and need.

Comment: Bldc is driven by mosfets, why not disabling the driver?

Answer (score 1):

First you cut the power of gate drivers, after you have inhibited them. Then a contactor/relay is the only option, I guess.